# Bigquery View is not doing the partition pruning

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This was marked duplicate but I believe the other issue does not answer the question as it talks about exposing a pseudocolumn in view and use that in filter condition.

I have a table where I write data in append only fashion and created a view to display only the latest entry for a reporting processes to consume. I have observed the bigquery optimizer does not prune the partitions when I query the data via view. This is what I have:

```
-- this table has approx 1TB of data
create table test.orders
(
order_num string,
order_datetime timestamp,
ingestion_timestamp timestamp,
retailer string,
status string
)
PARTITION BY DATE(order_datetime)
cluster by (retailer)
```

Now I have a view to show the latest information about the particular orders

```
create or replace view test.v_orders as
select * except(rnk) from
(select *, row_number() over (partition by retailer, order_num order by ingestion_timestamp desc) as rnk 
from `<project-id>.test.orders`) where rnk=1
```

When I query the data like this:

`Select * from test.orders where date(order_datetime)='2020-05-01' and retailer='abcd'` it scans ~50GB of data.

But when I query the data like:

`Select * from test.v_orders where date(order_datetime)='2020-05-01' and retailer='abcd'` it scans almost full 1TB of data.

I have two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong here - why does optimizer not able to prune the partitions?
2. Is there a better way to design a solution for above problem if we have an append only table and want to read only the latest data via a view?

Comment: I'll be interested if anyone can answer.  It is as if the developers of "views" and of "partitioned" tables work for different companies on different continents, so the two don't work together particularly well.

Comment: Mikhail you closed the question but can you elaborate how the question I asked and what you mentioned are related? In other question it is mentioned to expose _PARTITIONTIME pseudocolumn I already have a column that I have partitioned data on but optimizer does not do partition pruning.

Comment: @user780092 - you asked for "why" and "better way to design" and those two are answered in the post BigQuery Date-Partitioned Views given by one of the prominent [former] member of BigQuery Team

Comment: @user780092 I have the same issue than you. Were you able to resolve it by the other answer?